# How to query a four letter last name where 2nd letter is 'a'

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using the actor table in the dvdrental database. Write a query to count the number of distinct employees that either have a first name that starts with 'W' or a four-letter last name with the second letter 'a'.

Here is what I have so far for my query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM actor
WHERE LEFT(first_name, 1) = 'W'
OR ...
```

I am not sure how to go from here.

I solved the first part. I still need to figure out how to get this other condition for my WHERE clause:

"four-letter last name with the second letter 'a'."

I dont know hw to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `LIKE` operator here:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM actor
WHERE first_name LIKE 'W%' OR last_name LIKE '_a__';
```

Note that in `LIKE` syntax, `%` means any number of characters.  So `W%` means that the first name starts with `W` and is followed by zero or more of any character.  Underscore `_` means any single character, so `_a__` means a 4 letter last name, the second letter which is `a`.

Comment: My output seems fine. Although I am a little confused on what this question is asking for. When it says "four-letter last name with the second letter 'a' ", does that mean that every last name that has a 2nd letter 'a' also must end in 4 letters? Or not?

Comment: Good question.  My interpretation is that the last name must be exactly 4 characters, with the second character being an `a`.

Comment: When i run this query not all of my last names have four letters? Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to first figure out the requirement, then I can respond.  I have stated my interpretation above already.

Comment: So I ran: SELECT * FROM actor WHERE first_name LIKE 'W%' OR last_name LIKE '_a__'; just to see how many employees satisfied this condition and got 13. However, not all of the employees' last names were only four letters (i.e. Hoffman, Jolie, Nolte, Wilson) while some of them were (i.e. Torn, Cage).

Comment: `LIKE 'a_'` means _two_ letter last names which start with `a`.  You should review the docs for how `LIKE` works.

Comment: My requirement is this: I need to have a column of first names that start with capital 'W' or a column of last names that are "four letters" with 'a' as the second letter

Comment: We're going in circles now.  My answer already gives you this requirement.

Comment: Does this question say satisfy one condition (last name beginning with 'W) or two conditions (last name with four letters & last name with second letter 'a')? I am confused about the definition of OR here.

Comment: Your own question is using `or` between the two conditions, you are the one tell us what the question is, not the other way around.

Comment: Okay i rechecked and yes i see that all column values fulfill one of either requirement. So my problem is resolved and your answer does fulfill all parts.

Comment: For ex: full names. The name 'Woody Jolie' has a first name starting with W yet not a four letter last name with 2nd letter a; it fulfills one of the two requirements of OR. The name 'Zero Cage' will have a four-letter last name with 2nd letter a yet not a first name starting with W; it fulfills one of the two requirements of OR. Basically, my question is completely answered now.